# why is my site's footer stuck to the top of my page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[This is a Wordpresss site and I believe this is a theme issue that is causing the footer to stick to the top of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqi9m.jpg)

I can't figure out a site-wide fix for the issue. I have used:

```
.l-footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

and it just makes the footer disappear entirely.

Comment: Post all of your html and css, edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste the code, also you can link to the page

Comment: @mlegg http://www.gravitytransformation.com/videos/

Comment: @Jb11281992 Please add in applicable code / html to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:relative`, `position:fixed`, and `display:block` also. Once you have the right one, take a note on how they work and also see the changes that they made.

Comment: Oops– Horrible mistake on my side.

Comment: Yeah, they don't work either. The only thing that has successfully moved the footer was using position: absolute and then using margin-top:100%, but it's not consistent for all of my pages

Comment: Good to know; I know I did it a while ago but it may change depending how you made your site. Post this answer and put it as the accepted one for other users :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try this:

```
.somefooter {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Through I think one of them should do it, place them in your footer tag.